# Is there an equivalent to webmock for testing client side code

Tags: javascript, testing

Is there an equivalent to webmock or vcr for client side code? ... Or is it possible to use webmock with client side code already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use sinon's [FakeXMLHttpRequest](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#FakeXMLHttpRequest), or [nock](https://github.com/flatiron/nock).

Comment: +1 for nock. It has all of the features of webmock, and does recording too.

Answer (score 0):

[A rewriting web proxy for testing interactions between your browser and external sites. Works with ruby + rspec](https://github.com/oesmith/puffing-billy)

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, try [Mockttp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mockttp).

It can mock requests for both Node & browser, it uses real requests thereby giving you far more accurate results than Nock et al, and it can either mock as a fake server (reconfiguring your target URLs) or an intercepting proxy (making requests to the real URLs, and intercepting some/all of them).

It's also got good support for running tests in parallel, which global-mocking libraries can't do, and lots of other nice modern features.